# Animation Nodes: Transform Mesh with multiple objects as input?

Tags: animation-nodes

The "Transform Mesh" node in AN multiplies an input mesh according to given amount of points of the matrix input.

I would like to vary the kind of object, that e.g. when my input matrix has 9 vectors, on each point a random object from a collection of 3 objects is set.

But it seems I can only enter a single mesh / single object here.

[image]

(It is for me necessary to do it with "transform mesh" since in the end I am using thousands of vector points, only with "transform mesh" I could do this in AN without crash.)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Random List` node to generate mesh list.

[image]